# Compare 2 DataTables and Select Rows Not in 2nd table Using 2 Criteria

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I need this function for a transaction table. My datatables looks like this.

RecordsInDatabase-Table

```
a_code | b_code
AB     | 001
AB     | 002
AC     | 001
```

RecordsInTextFile-Table

```
a_code | b_code
AB     | 002
AC     | 005
AC     | 009
```

I need to compare using two IDs, `a_code` and `b_code`.
Therefore, if I run the LINQ code (or other), a datable would contain records that are IN the database, but NOT in the text file.

RecordsNotInTextFile-Table

```
a_code | b_code
AB     | 001
AC     | 001
```

I already have a LINQ code, but it only compares using one ID.

```
DataTable affixesInDatabase = affixDAO.SelectAllAffix();
            IEnumerable<string> affixesNotInTextFile = affixesInDatabase.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r.Field<string>("affix_code"))
                .Except(affixesInTextFile.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r.Field<string>("affix_code")));
            if (affixesNotInTextFile.Any())
            {
                DataTable affixesToBeDeleted = (from row in affixesInDatabase.AsEnumerable()
                                                join id in affixesNotInTextFile
                                                on row.Field<string>("affix_code") equals id
                                                select row).CopyToDataTable();
                foreach (DataRow dr in affixesToBeDeleted.Rows)
                {
                    affixDAO.DeleteAffix(dr[0].ToString());
                }
            }
            return "Affix data successfully edited.";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to filter out two exceptions, the simplest way to do it would be to chain two `.Except()` calls into your LINQ expression.

From your comment, it appears that you aren't familiar with the principles on which LINQ operates.  If you want to understand, I'd suggest reading [Jon Skeet's "Edulinq" series](http://edulinq.googlecode.com/hg/posts/index.html), in which he re-implements the standard LINQ query operators and explains how it all works as he goes.  But here's the short version:

LINQ is a set of extension methods that operate on *enumerable sequences* (ie. `IEnumerable<T>`).  Each method takes a sequence as input and applies some operation, and the majority of them produce a new sequence as output.  (There are some that produce a single value instead, but not the ones we're dealing with.)  So here's what your query is doing:

```
IEnumerable<string> affixesNotInTextFile = //assignment. You know how that works
affixesInDatabase //our base sequence that we're starting from
.AsEnumerable() //ensure that we're working with an IEnumerable, not an IQueryable
.Select() //transform the sequence from the original objects to a sequence of Field<string> values from the original objects
.Except() //filter out of the transformed sequence anything that's in *this* sequence
```

`Except()` produces a new sequence, and so you can chain another `.Except()` on the end of the expression that will filter the sequence further.  Read the Edulinq posts, and pay particular attention to the ones on `Select` and `Except`, and you should come out of it understanding how LINQ works well enough to accomplish what you need.

Comment: How? I'm fairly new to LINQ and I got my code from SO as well.

Comment: @JeanoErmitaño Edited to provide a bit more guidance.

Comment: Thanks for providing the link. Much appreciated. I'll get back to you when I solve it on my own. Thanks!

Comment: @MasonWheeler I need to compare using two IDs, does this mean I should select the same base sequence with two `.Select()`?

Comment: @JeanoErmitaño: That would make sense, if the two IDs are both fields of the same base object.

Comment: @MasonWheeler In my case, they are. The base object contains two columns, and I need to compare both to another datatable. My current LINQ looks like `baseSequence.Select().Except(Select()).Select().Except(Select())` which I find looks a bit odd.

Comment: @MasonWheeler To be exact, here's my code: `IEnumerable<string> establishmentCertificatesNotInTextFile = establishmentCertificatesInDatabase.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r.Field<string>("education_establishment_code"))
                    .Except(establishmentCertificatesInTextFile.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r.Field<string>("education_establishment_code")))
                    .Select(r => r.Field<string>("certificate_code"))
                    .Except(establishmentCertificatesInTextFile.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r.Field<string>("certificate_code")));`

Comment: @JeanoErmitaño: That probably won't compile, actually, because after the first `Select` on the base sequence, we're dealing with a transformed sequence of `Field<string>` objects. Unless those fields contain sub-fields of their own, calling `Select` again on it the way you do is likely to break.

Comment: @MasonWheeler I'm quite confused now. I've seen the `SelectMany` option and a `GroupBy` option in another. And also what you've said, it is possible to do two `Select`s, assuming the IDs are in the same base sequence.

Comment: I figured that because I want to select two IDs, the assignment should contain two strings to correspond to each ID. Am I right?

Comment: I need help, I'm lost.